# Dynamic Interpretation Button Label Loses Formatting on Copy and Paste

Tags: front-end, output-formatting, gui-construction, cells, number-representation

I have an [`Interpretation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpretation.html) [`Button`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Button.html) that displays its label correctly on evaluation. However, when I copy and paste it as input the label loses its formatting.

```
Interpretation[{x = RandomReal[]}, Button[Dynamic[N[x, 6]], x = RandomReal[]], N[x, 6]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

When this is copy and pasted into an input cell it changes to:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

How can I get it to retain its label formatting which should be the 6 decimal place number?

Also, I though [`N`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html) was cutting the number down to 6 significant figures.  This is obviously not the case since the machine precision number is showing up in the label.  What have I missed here, as well?

Comment: It's because an input cell displays the number input form, which is what you are seeing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because `"Input"` cell style has `NumberMarks -> True` while `"Output"` inherits default `False`.

You can set `BaseStyle -> NumberMarks -> False` for the `Button`:

```
Interpretation[
 {x = RandomReal[]}, 
 Button[Dynamic[N[x, 6]], x = RandomReal[], BaseStyle -> NumberMarks -> False], 
 N[x, 6]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

As an option

```
Interpretation[{x = RandomReal[]}, Button[Dynamic@ToString@SetPrecision[x, 6], 
               x = RandomReal[]], N[x, 6]]
```

Or

```
Interpretation[{x = RandomReal[]}, Button[Dynamic@N@Round[x, 1*^-6], 
               x = RandomReal[]], N@Round[x, 1*^-6]]
```

As far as I understand, `N` really doesn't change anything about a machine number, not even its precision, it does most of the work on exact inputs. So for machine numbers you need to use `SetPrecision` at the very least.